# How could I have optional/flexible TypeScript typed in a function signature?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have the following example function signature:

```
(e: Event | React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: number | number[]) => void
```

But what I really want is to have the ability to accept functions that have any combination of:

```
(e: Event, value: number) => void
(e: Event, value: number[]) => void
(e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: number) => void
(e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: number[]) => void
```

But TypeScript is really annoying and would only accept the exact same signature... What is the correct way to make the TypeScript function signature a little bit more "acceptable", "flexible" or "smarter"?

I kinda don't want to have the following though:

```
type MyFuncSig = 
  (e: Event, value: number) => void |
  (e: Event, value: number[]) => void | 
  (e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: number) => void |
  (e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: number[]) => void;
```

Edit:
The original function signature in question, is actually from [Material UI's Slider](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slider/#props) (see: `onChange` and `onChangeCommitted`)

Comment: What is your objection to the union signature? Additionally, I imagine you are using this signature as the parameter type for a callback function. How do you determine, when it is time to invoke the callback, which type of event (regular or synthetic) to pass to the callback? If the callback function doesn't accept both, it may lead to a runtime error if you give it the wrong type, since a synthetic event is missing properties that a regular event would have.

Comment: Are you aware of [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)? Edit: I guess it doesn't help if you need a type declaration though. But the union type you wrote covers that just fine.

Comment: Well, the original function signature is from Material UI's Slider. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slider/#props (see: onChangeCommitted), when I provide the values, I know I'm setting and getting 2 values (hence array), so I know my callback will be getting an array. However, my callback itself, I must specify `number | number[]` otherwise tslint will complaint despite I know full well that I would be receiving an array.